# Preferred data type for color

Tags: database, database-design, nosql, schema

I use a NoSQL db and was thinking of filtering the documents (products) based on colors user choose. What should be the preferred data type for the color field integer or string and why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Choose String**

There are many codes of colors

hexadecimal e.g #ff0000

RGB e.g  rgb(255, 0, 0)

HSL e.g   hsl(0, 100%, 50%)

You don't mention the code you will choose.

And  as I see most of them  if not all are of character types.

So for no doubt choose string unless you sure they will be stored as numbers.